# Downloading files using wildcards with scp in Ruby

Tags: ruby, scp

I am successfully downloading the log files in "log_list" from the server to destination using the code below.
I am using net/ssh / net/scp : (https://github.com/net-ssh/net-scp)

```
log_list = ["ini.log", "syslog.log", "network.log"]
fetch(log_list)


    def fetch(fetchlogs)
        root_cli do |ssh|
    
          fetchlogs.each do |testlog|
              source= "/var/log/logfiles/#{testlog}"
              destination = "/home/Documents/testdir/"
              
              ssh.scp.download!(source,destination)
    
            rescue Exception => e
              info "#{fetch} is not a valid file ==++==++ "
            end
        end
      end
```

Now the log files in "log_list" are rotating logs and can have multiple files like "ini.log ,ini.log.001, ini.log.002, ..." and i want to download all what i tried is with *:

```
log_list = ["ini.log*", "syslog.log*", "network.log*"]
```

which normally i thought should work but this is resulting in no file with exception.

```
ini.log* is not a valid file ==++==++
syslog.log* is not a valid file ==++==++
network.log* is not a valid file ==++==++
```

I also tried with adding * directly to source instead in log_list

```
source = "/var/log/logfiles/#{testlog}*"
pp " source #{source}"

ssh.scp.download!(source,"/home/Documents/testdir/")
```

output:

```
source ini.log*
source syslog.log*
source network.log*
```

but files are not being downloaded with same error

```
ini.log* is not a valid file ==++==++
syslog.log* is not a valid file ==++==++
network.log* is not a valid file ==++==++
```

Although files exits, Does somebody have any idea, is * character is being escaped ? !!

Comment: It would help if you included what library you're using for SSH instead of assuming people know what object `ssh` is.

Comment: i am using net/scp (https://github.com/net-ssh/net-scp)

Comment: You can see in the [source](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-scp/blob/5031c1239c8413fec2d4e4b925c07db2611cbfdd/lib/net/scp.rb#L351) that it's [shell escaping](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) the remote filename. I can't find a way to defeat this escaping so that the remote will actually glob the filename. You may have to implement custom code to do this by modifying what you see net/scp doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scp.session.exec!` with `ls` to gather a list of files based on your wildcard choice, and then download each source file one by one.

Something along these lines:

```
log_list = ["ini.log*", "syslog.log*", "network.log*"]

...
fetchlogs.each do |testlog|
  source = "/var/log/logfiles/#{testlog}"
  destination = "/home/Documents/testdir/"
  
  # Fetch list of wildcard files using ls
  source_files = ssh.scp.session.exec!("ls #{source}").split
  
  source_files.each { |file|         
    ssh.scp.download!(file, destination)
  }

  ...
end
```